# Merge datas from an array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [2018/03/01] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [BIL_Date] => 2018/03/01
                    [BIL_RateNonTaxed] => 105.00
                    [BIL_RateTaxed] => 115.500000000
                    [BIL_Status] => notcharged
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [BIL_Date] => 2018/03/01
                    [BIL_RateNonTaxed] => 60.00
                    [BIL_RateTaxed] => 63.000000000
                    [BIL_Status] => charged
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [BIL_Date] => 2018/03/01
                    [BIL_RateNonTaxed] => 21.00
                    [BIL_RateTaxed] => 25.194750000
                    [BIL_Status] => notcharged
                ) 
        )
)
```

How can I merge some datas to have something like this ?

I search to group by date, item `charged` and `notcharged`.

```
Array
(
    [2018/03/01] => Array
        (
            [notcharged] => Array
                (
                    [BIL_RateNonTaxed] => 126.00
                    [BIL_RateTaxed] => 140.69475
                )
            [charged] => Array
                (
                    [BIL_RateNonTaxed] => 60.00
                    [BIL_RateTaxed] => 63.000000000
                )
        )
)
```

Here what I tried:

```
$datas = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $element) {
    $datas[$key][] = "BIL_RateNonTaxed" => $key['BIL_RateNonTaxed'];
    $datas[$key][] = "BIL_RateTaxed" => $key['BIL_RateTaxed'];
}
```

Could you please help me with this please ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is invalid code.

Comment: What is `$array`? Full array or item under `2018/03\01` key?

Comment: @u_mulder, `array` is the total array containing all the datas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop thru the array and use `array_reduce` to summarize the data.

```
$array = array
(
    "2018/03/01" => array
        (
           array
                (
                    "BIL_Date" => '2018/03/01',
                    "BIL_RateNonTaxed" => '105.00',
                    "BIL_RateTaxed" => '115.500000000',
                    "BIL_Status" => 'notcharged'
                ),

            array
                (
                    "BIL_Date" => '2018/03/01',
                    "BIL_RateNonTaxed" => '60.00',
                    "BIL_RateTaxed" => '63.000000000',
                    "BIL_Status" => 'charged'
                ),

           array
                (
                    "BIL_Date" => '2018/03/01',
                    "BIL_RateNonTaxed" => '21.00',
                    "BIL_RateTaxed" => '25.194750000',
                    "BIL_Status" => 'notcharged'
                ) 
        ),
);

$result = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $element) {
    $result[ $key ] = array_reduce( $element, function ($c, $v) {
        if( !isset( $c[ $v["BIL_Status"] ] ) ) {
            $c[ $v["BIL_Status"] ] = array(
                "BIL_RateNonTaxed" => $v["BIL_RateNonTaxed"],
                "BIL_RateTaxed" => $v["BIL_RateTaxed"],
            );
        } else {
            $c[ $v["BIL_Status"] ] = array(
                "BIL_RateNonTaxed" => ( $c[ $v["BIL_Status"] ]["BIL_RateNonTaxed"] + $v["BIL_RateNonTaxed"] ),
                "BIL_RateTaxed" => ( $c[ $v["BIL_Status"] ]["BIL_RateTaxed"] + $v["BIL_RateTaxed"] ),
            );
        }
        return $c;
    }, array() );
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [2018/03/01] => Array
        (
            [notcharged] => Array
                (
                    [BIL_RateNonTaxed] => 126
                    [BIL_RateTaxed] => 140.69475
                )

            [charged] => Array
                (
                    [BIL_RateNonTaxed] => 60.00
                    [BIL_RateTaxed] => 63.000000000
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $element) {
    // init every date with empty values
    $datas[$key][] = [
        'notcharged' => [
            'BIL_RateNonTaxed' => 0,
            'BIL_RateTaxed' => 0,
        ],
        'charged' => [
            'BIL_RateNonTaxed' => 0,
            'BIL_RateTaxed' => 0,
        ],
    ];
    // iterate over `$element`
    foreach ($element as $item) {
        $datas[$key][$item['BIL_Status']]['BIL_RateNonTaxed'] += $item['BIL_RateNonTaxed'];
        $datas[$key][$item['BIL_Status']]['BIL_RateTaxed'] += $item['BIL_RateTaxed'];
    }
}
```